# What is the analog of "monotonic" for scalar functions on surfaces?

Tags: critical-point-theory, definitions, curves-and-surfaces

"monotonic" is well defined for functions $f(x)$, where e.g. $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$. The quality I particularly care about is that if $f(x)$ is monotonic then it will not have any local extrema for $x\in(0,1)$.

Is there an analogous word for a function $g(x,y)$ with $x,y\in[0,1]$ and $g(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$, where $g(x,y)$ has no local extrema for $x,y\in(0,1)$?

Comment: "Inverse image of a contractible set is contractible" is what I have often thought the correct generalization of monotonicity to higher dimensions to be, and it fits your requested criteria. But I don't know a word for it.

Comment: WHat about "open"?

Comment: Constant functions are monotone but are only open in trivial cases. $\:$ Will's suggested criterion would never hold for (non-empty) disconnected domains and contractible ranges. $\:$ (I don't have my own suggestion at this point.) $\;\;$

Comment: @Will: Your notion is very close to "cell-like" map. 

Comment: @mangledorf: Do you consider only continuous functions? Otherwise, it's unlikely you will get a nice generalization. 

Comment: There is a standard notion of "monotonic vector field", it is defined using the following inequality: 
$$\langle v_p-v_q,p-q\rangle>0.$$ 

Comment: @Ricky: There is a good reason for that, I think. Any definition of monotonicity that a) depends only on topology and b) never says a function on a subset of the real line is monotonic when it isn't has that property.

@Misha: I'll look it up.

Comment: I'm OK with only considering continuous functions, but ideally the word would be a catch all like monotonic is in 1d.

Comment: For instance, there are open maps ${\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}$ which are discontinuous everywhere (cf. Igor's suggestion). By the way, you can also use the class of submersions (this makes sense in both continuous and smooth setting). This is more restrictive than Igor's suggestion (except for functions of one variable), but behaves nicer in some ways. All in all, I think the answer depends on what are you going to do with this generalization. 

Comment: @Misha: I would like to use this word to say the following: Given the value of an unknown function $g(x,y)$ with $x=[0,1]$ or $y=[0,1]$ (that is, on the boundary of $(x,y) \in [0,1]$, we find values for the function $g(x,y)$ with $(x,y) \in (0,1)$ such that $g(x,y)$ is _________ there. Where ______ is the word that means "has no local extrema".

Comment: What about "harmonic for some conformal structure" ?

Comment: @BS: I like this but it's just as hard/long to say as "lacks local extrema"

Comment: BTW, we decided to just abuse the term monotonic for our paper: http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/monotonic/